# Tesseract.js throw Error(data) cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_malloc') in tesseract file

Tags: tesseract.js

I'm trying to use tesseract to convert image to text by upload image to my web app but got the error in the tesseract create worker.js like _malloc is undefined in throw Error(data).
I'm using tesseract version 2.1.5,
and I wrote the code from the video in 2019, I think maybe tesseract is changed from that time.

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx9M5.png)

This is code in app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
const multer = require("multer");
const {createWorker} = require("tesseract.js");
const worker = createWorker({
   logger: m => console.log(m)
});

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./uploads");
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage}).single("fname");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/upload', (req,res) => {
    upload(req, res, err => {
        fs.readFile(`./uploads/${req.file.originalname}`, (err, data) => {
            if(err) return console.log("Error", err);

            worker
            .recognize('./uploads/op.png')
            .then(result => {
                res.send(result.txt);
            })
            .finally(() => worker.terminate());
        });
    });
});
```